# Groovy meta class interoperability with Java 8

Tags: java, groovy, java-8, metaclass

**Introduction:**

I'm developing a Java library called [awaitility](http://awaitility.googlecode.com) which also has a Groovy extension. Prior to Java 8 you could use the library like this:

```
// Syntax example with the Groovy extension
await().atMost(500, MILLISECONDS).until { asynch.getValue() == 2 }
```

The Groovy extension makes use of a class called `ConditionFactory` defined in the Java API. But this API doesn't define an until method that takes an instance of a Groovy Closure. So instead the method is added with a meta class like this:

```
ConditionFactory.metaClass.until { Closure closure ->
      delegate.until(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        Boolean call() {
          return closure.call();
        }
      });
    }
```

As you can see it simply delegates to the `until` method in the Java API that takes an instance of `Callable<Boolean>`.

**The Problem:**

The Java API also contains an overloaded method of `until` that takes a `Runnable` as its parameter. When the Groovy extension is used with Java 8 the `Runnable` version of the `until` method is called instead of the `until` method taking `Closure` as an argument (the method defined using `metaClass`). It seems like the metaClass is no longer kicking in. Why is this? Is there a work-around?

Comment: Wild hypothesis: `Closure` is not a `@FunctionalInterface`? What is its prototype?

Comment: Closure is not a functional interface but now that I look closer it does implement Runnable! I suppose that could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't think this has anything to do with Java 8 (sorry for the confusion). A work-around to my problem looked like this:

```
def originalMethod = ConditionFactory.metaClass.getMetaMethod("until", Runnable.class)
ConditionFactory.metaClass.until { Runnable runnable ->
  if (runnable instanceof Closure) {
    delegate.until(new Callable<Boolean>() {
      Boolean call() {
        return (runnable as Closure).call();
      }
    });
  } else {
    originalMethod.invoke(delegate, runnable)
  }
}
```